# Cant use "extend" command in Java, otherwhise program crashes

Tags: java, user-interface, extends

I have a little problem with my classes. My programm works fine, at least if I only create an instance of the Gui class, but if I use the "extend" command on another class to extend the Gui class, the created Gui gives me several error messages. I have two classes, the Gui Class and the "Hashings" Class. If I dont use "extend Gui" on the Hashings class everything is fine, but If I do so I get those errors:

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at sun.awt.Win32GraphicsConfig.getBounds(Native Method)
    at sun.awt.Win32GraphicsConfig.getBounds(Win32GraphicsConfig.java:222)
    at java.awt.Window.init(Window.java:505)
    at java.awt.Window.<init>(Window.java:537)
    at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:420)
    at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:385)
    at javax.swing.JFrame.<init>(JFrame.java:189)
    at Gui.<init>(Gui.java:33)
    at Hashings.<init>(Hashings.java:1)
    at Gui.<init>(Gui.java:29)
    at Hashings.<init>(Hashings.java:1)
```

Here is the Hashings class:

```
  public class Hashings extends Gui{
  }
```

And here the Gui class (a little confusing)

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;


public class Gui extends JFrame
{ 

 public static void main (String[] args) {

    }     

 BorderLayout b1 = new BorderLayout();  

 public int anzahl;
 public int ascii;
 int e;

 JTextField name = new JTextField(8);
 JButton confirm2 = new JButton("Einfügen");
 JTextField name2 = new JTextField(5);
 JButton confirm3 = new JButton("Suchen");

 JPanel b = new JPanel();
 JPanel c = new JPanel();
 JPanel a = new JPanel();
 Label[] lab = new Label[10];
 Hashings h = new Hashings();

    public Gui() { 

    super();
    addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
      public void windowClosing(WindowEvent evt) { dispose(); }
    });
    int frameWidth = 1280; 
    int frameHeight = 7;
    setSize(frameWidth, frameHeight);
    Dimension d = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    int x = (d.width - getSize().width) / 2;
    int y = (d.height - getSize().height) / 2;
    setLocation(x, y);
    setTitle("Gui");
    setResizable(false);


    b.add(name); 
    b.add(confirm2);
    b.add(HashMethod);
    c.add(name2);
    c.add(confirm3);
    this.add(b,BorderLayout.NORTH);
    this.add(a,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    this.add(c,BorderLayout.SOUTH); 


 for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
     lab[i]=new Label("leer");
    }



  for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
     a.add(lab[i]);
    }

  setVisible(true);  

 } 

}
```

Comment: And dont forget that the Gui class works perfectly fine, If I dont use the other class ;)

Comment: Sorry, I don‘t get it. Why do you want to extend Hashings with Gui? What is your aim? Looking at your current code, Gui will use methods Hashings provides but Hashings doesn‘t need a Gui at all?!

Comment: I need to use Guis Parameters like "int e" in Hashings

Comment: Mutually dependent classes - uh. You are saying *Every `Hashings` **is** a `Gui`. Every `Gui` **has a** `Hashings`* - guess what?

Comment: Does any answer solve your problem or do you still need help?

Comment: Yeag thanks I understood it but I have a new problem ( I made another post)

Answer (score 0):

In your stack trace, there is this interesting segment.

```
at Gui.<init>(Gui.java:33)
at Hashings.<init>(Hashings.java:1)
at Gui.<init>(Gui.java:29)
at Hashings.<init>(Hashings.java:1)
```

What you've done is created an infinite loop.  The creation of the initial Hashings object calls the Gui init method.  Within the Gui, you have a Hashings field getting constructed.  So every time a Hashings is created, it inits the Gui which creates a new Hashings, which inits a new Gui, which creates a new Hashings...
This causes a stackoverflow because eventually you will run out of memory.

```
Label[] lab = new Label[10];
Hashings h = new Hashings();

public Gui() {
```

To fix this problem you have to break the loop of commands, probably by removing the Hashings field.

EDIT:
To fix this problem and have access to Gui's integers, I would move the constructor of Hashings to be inside the Gui constructor.

```
Label[] lab = new Label[10];

public Gui() {
      Hashings h = new Hashings(this);
```

Then

```
public class Hashings {
  private Gui gui;
  public Hashings(Gui g)
  {
    gui = g;
  } 
}
```

Since your Gui int fields are public, you could use those directly, but I prefer adding getter and setter methods.

Comment: I need the Hashings Object to use the class. Can you tell me any alternative please how to get out of this loop?

Answer (score 0):

There is an instance created `Hashings h = new Hashings();` in the class `Gui`.

The first instantiation of `Gui` calls the constructor of `Hashings` which itself calls the default constructor of `Gui`. Now there is the cyclic instatntiation loop until the stack overflows and you get your exception.

Just put some output to `System.err` in the constructor of `Gui` to confirm it.

Comment: Hey man, thanks for answering. Do you maybe have an idea what I can do still use the instance of Hashings but avoid the loop

Comment: @Marko You can't. If you want to use Hashings, either don't have it extend Gui, or don't have one in Gui and just create a Hashings (which is a Gui) and use it. You can't do both. It's like trying to put your car in the trunk of your car and go for a drive.

Comment: How can I use the integers of Gui in Hashings than :( ?

Comment: As the integers are public you can access them from your instance: `Gui g=new Gui(); System.out.println(g.anzahl);`. But it would be better to encapuslate them as private and only have getters and setters to access them. That would make it possible to modify the implementation later on without Breaking the public interface. (eg if you always calculate the integers instead of storing.)